Total data count differ when try Count method and while uploading complete data in data table
I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application in which I'm trying to load 5k of data at one time and and another 5k when user reaches last page, but while loading data total records come as 5181 but at bottom of data tables it shows 5178 entries, as shown in the screenshots.
While using
int totalRecords = devices.Count();


For paginated data in below table for data tables

My C# controller code is here, for initial loading and when user reaches last page:
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
{
    // Check if session exists and retrieve the username
    var username = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Username");

    if (username == null)
    {
        // If no session exists, redirect to the Account Index page
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
    }

    var devices = await _context.GetDeviceMigrationsAsync();

    int totalRecords = devices.Count();

    int start = 0;
    int length = 5000; // Total data to fetch in each request

    // Order the devices by LastUpdatedTime in descending order
    var orderedDevices = devices.OrderByDescending(d => d.LastUpdatedTime);

    // Perform pagination on the server side
    var paginatedDevices = orderedDevices.Skip(start).Take(length).Select(d => new DeviceMigration
    {
        ID = d.ID,
        DeviceSerial = d.DeviceSerial ?? "-",
        DeviceName = d.DeviceName ?? "-",
        UserName = d.UserName ?? "-",
        EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID ?? "-",
        UserEmail = d.UserEmail ?? "-",
        OverallStatus = d.OverallStatus ?? "-",
        LastUpdatedTime = d.LastUpdatedTime,
        WaveNumber = d.WaveNumber ?? "-"
    }).ToList();

    // Prepare distinct wave numbers
    var waveNumbers = devices
        .Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.WaveNumber))
        .Select(d => d.WaveNumber)
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();

    var statusCounts = devices
        .Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.OverallStatus))  // Filter out null or empty statuses
        .GroupBy(d => d.OverallStatus)
        .Select(g => new { Status = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
        .ToDictionary(sc => sc.Status, sc => sc.Count);

    // Find the minimum ID 
    int minId = paginatedDevices.Min(d => d.ID);

    // Output the minimum ID (optional: for debugging or logging)
    Console.WriteLine("Minimum ID: " + minId);
    // Pass data to the view
    ViewBag.WaveNumbers = waveNumbers;
    ViewBag.StatusCounts = statusCounts;
    ViewBag.TotalCounts = totalRecords;

    return View(paginatedDevices);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GetMoreDeviceData(int page = 1, int pageSize = 5000, int lastDataId = 0)
{
    // Get devices ordered by ID to ensure correct pagination based on last ID
    var devices = await _context.GetDeviceMigrationsAsync();

    // Filter devices where ID is greater than lastDataId
    var filteredDevices = devices
        .Where(d => d.ID < lastDataId)
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastUpdatedTime); // Order by ascending ID

    // Count the total number of filtered devices
    int filteredDevicesCount = filteredDevices.Count();

    // Take the next 5000 or fewer records after lastDataId
    var paginatedDevices = filteredDevices.Take(pageSize).Select(d => new DeviceMigration
    {
        ID = d.ID,
        DeviceSerial = d.DeviceSerial ?? "-",
        DeviceName = d.DeviceName ?? "-",
        UserName = d.UserName ?? "-",
        EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID ?? "-",
        UserEmail = d.UserEmail ?? "-",
        OverallStatus = d.OverallStatus ?? "-",
        LastUpdatedTime = d.LastUpdatedTime,
        WaveNumber = d.WaveNumber ?? "-"
    }).ToList();

    // Return the data as JSON
    return Json(new { data = paginatedDevices });
}

Can anyone suggest me where I'm going wrong?
As while running a SQL query as in database, total count is returned as 5181, but when I capture min ID after initial data load and run a query after that, it shows 178 rows remaining.
Any help will be thankfully received.

Remove your filter and try, it might be ur filter issues

You're ordering by the updated time, so unless that is exactly the same order as the ID your starting ID for the next page will have skipped some. For example suppose you have 1,2,3,4 and a page size of 2. Once ordered by time they might be 1,3,2,4; First page has 1,3; next page anything above 3, so only 4 - 2 has been skipped.
Two other comments on your code: there's duplication, use the same code for the first page (start is hardcoded to zero, never changes) and the subsequent pages. Also the comments no longer match the code, a good example of why comments can be worse than no comments.

Another point to consider: you call the database for each page and every time pull back all the data. Either query for just the page of data, or query once and cache the data. Which you do will depend on how big you expect the whole table to eventually be, and whether you need to include new data as a user scrolls through the pages.

Are there any filtering conditions that cause some records not to be loaded? For example, empty fields or records that do not meet certain conditions. Has the data in the database been changed or deleted during the loading process?
